# Does Theora Decoder in libavcodec (FFMPEG V0.5) support YUV422 YUV444 modes?

Tags: ffmpeg, theora

I am working on theora decoder in ffmpeg V0.5. When i try to decode a 422 or 444 ogg/ogv bit stream using ffmpeg, the output yuv is junk. When i checked the ffmpeg source code, i saw that a  pixel format is hardcoded to PIX_FMT_YUV420P.

Does theora decoder in ffmpeg/libavcodec support decoding of YUV422/YUV444 mode bit streams?

thanks,

-AD.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you're looking for, but have you tried [ffmpeg2theora](http://v2v.cc/~j/ffmpeg2theora/)?